# WinDirStat freezes whenever I click the "Clean Up" button in the menu bar

Tags: windirstat

This happens every time on my desktop, and has never happened on my laptop. I tried reinstalling and restarting multiple times. My best guess is there's a problem with my system configuration/registry/etc.

Edit: It's probably not a filesystem issue, as it occurs even in a folder on a different drive with a single .txt file.

Edit 2: I'm running Windows 10 Pro, build 19043.1165.

Comment: How long did you wait.  Due to the way WinDirStat works and how much your actually removing it could take awhile to complete the operation

Comment: Assuming Windows 10, try the initial cleanup steps:  Open cmd.exe with run as administrator; dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup  ; dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image /restorehealth  ; sfc /scannow  ;  restart and test.

Comment: @John thank you so much. It works now

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the solution proposed in the comments by John.

```
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup

dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

sfc /scannow
```